# What invariant do RRB-trees maintain?

Tags: algorithm, scala, data-structures, clojure, tree

[Relaxed Radix Balanced Trees](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/169879/files/RMTrees.pdf) (RRB-trees) are a generalization of immutable vectors (used in Clojure and Scala) that have 'effectively constant' indexing and update times. RRB-trees maintain efficient indexing and update but also allow efficient concatenation (log n).

The authors present the data structure in a way that I find hard to follow. I am not quite sure what the invariant is that each node maintains.

In section 2.5, they describe their algorithm. I think they are ensuring that indexing into the node will only ever require e extra steps of linear search after radix searching. I do not understand how they derived their formula for the extra steps, and I think perhaps I'm not sure what each of the variables mean (in particular "a total of p sub-tree branches").

What's how does the RRB-tree concatenation algorithm work?

Comment: One thing I find confusing about their presentation is that it is not possible for _every_ node to be degree-m or degree-(m-1) for all vector sizes. Consider for example m=8 and a vector of length 80. I assume that the right spine is allowed to have arbitrary degree, but if they say that in the paper I missed it.

Comment: @BenYlvisaker asks if the RRB vector's right spine is allowed to have arbitrary degree. Two years later :-), here's an answer. Yes: all nodes of an RRB tree should contain between (*m* - *e*) and *m* child nodes, where *e* is the allowable flex factor — *except* for the rightmost spine of the tree, whose may safely contain fewer than *m* - *e* children. (For a 32-way vector, *e* = 2 is a decent choice). Bagwell and Rompf don't mention that in their paper, but Jean Niklas L'orange does mention it in his [master's thesis about RRB trees](http://hypirion.com/thesis.pdf).

Answer (score 8):

They do describe an invariant in section 2.4 "However, as mentioned earlier
B-Trees nodes do not facilitate radix searching. Instead we chose
the initial invariant of allowing the node sizes to range between `m`
and `m - 1`. This defines a family of balanced trees starting with
well known 2-3 trees, 3-4 trees and (for m=32) 31-32 trees. This
invariant ensures balancing and achieves radix branch search in the
majority of cases. Occasionally a few step linear search is needed
after the radix search to find the correct branch.
The extra steps required increase at the higher levels."

Looking at their formula, it looks like they have worked out the maximum and minimum possible number of values stored in a subtree. The difference between the two is the maximum possible difference between the maximum and minimum number of values underneath a point. If you divide this by the number of values underneath a slot, you have the maximum number of slots you could be off by when you work out which slot to look at to see if it contains the index you are searching for.

Comment: My reading is that this is an initial algorithm they choose as a stepping stone. Section 2.5 says they use a less constrained approach.  I think perhaps I should try to derive their formula by working out the max and min number of stored values like you say.

Answer (score 4):

@mcdowella is correct that's what they say about relaxed nodes.  But if you're splitting and joining nodes, a range from *m* to *m*-1 means you will sometimes have to adjust up to *m*-1 (*m*-2?) nodes in order to add or remove a single element from a node.  This seems horribly inefficient.  I think they meant between *m* and (2 *m*) - 1 because this allows nodes to be split into 2 when they get too big, or 2 nodes joined into one when they are too small without ever needing to change a third node.  So it's a typo that the "2" is missing in "2 *m*" in the paper.  [Jean Niklas L’orange's masters thesis](http://hypirion.com/thesis.pdf) backs me up on this.

Furthermore, all strict nodes have the same length which must be a power of 2.  The reason for this is an optimization in Rich Hickey's Clojure PersistentVector.  Well, I think the important thing is to pack all strict nodes left (more on this later) so you don't have to guess which branch of the tree to descend.  But being able to bit-shift and bit-mask instead of   divide is a nice bonus.  I didn't time the get() operation on a relaxed Scala Vector, but the [relaxed Paguro vector is about 10x slower than the strict one](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D0bjfsHpmK7aJzyE2WwArlioI6w69YhZ2f-x0yM6_Z0/edit#gid=1756774656).  So it makes every effort to be as strict as possible, even producing 2 strict levels if you repeatedly insert at 0.

Their tree also has an even height - all leaf nodes are equal distance from the root.  I think it would still work if relaxed trees had to be within, say, one level of one-another, though not sure what that would buy you.

Relaxed nodes can have strict children, but not vice-versa.

Strict nodes must be filled from the left (low-index) without gaps.  Any non-full Strict nodes must be on the right-hand (high-index) edge of the tree.  All Strict leaf nodes can always be full if you do appends in a focus or tail (more on that below).

You can see most of the invariants by searching for the debugValidate() methods in the [Paguro implementation](https://github.com/GlenKPeterson/Paguro/blob/master/src/main/java/org/organicdesign/fp/collections/RrbTree.java#L123).  That's not their paper, but it's mostly based on it.  Actually, the "display" variables in the [Scala implementation](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Vector.scala) aren't mentioned in the paper either.  If you're going to study this stuff, you probably want to start by taking a good look at the Clojure [PersistentVector](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentVector.java) because the RRB Tree has one inside it.  The two differences between that and the RRB Tree are 1. the RRB Tree allows "relaxed" nodes and 2. the RRB Tree may have a "focus" instead of a "tail."  Both focus and tail are small buffers (maybe the same size as a strict leaf node), the difference being that the focus will probably be localized to whatever area of the vector was last inserted/appended to, while the tail is always at the end (PerSistentVector can only be appended to, never inserted into).  These 2 differences are what allow O(log n) arbitrary inserts and removals, plus O(log n) split() and join() operations.